# How to avoid VS Web-Essentials 2013 changing encoding when minify JS files?

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

All my js files are encoding in "Western (Windows 1252)" when WebEssentials minify my js files the .min.js encoding change to "UTF-8 with BOM" i didn't found any options to keep the same file encoding in the .min.js